# Extra CSS supplied by JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I am trying to copy [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/), but it seems like JSFiddle is injecting some extra CSS, which is causing the copy to display differently than the version on JSFiddle.

How can I make the copy look like the JSFiddle result?

I tried copying the source of the `<iframe>`, but that didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Demo of simple tabs without jQuery UI - jsFiddle demo by syahrasi</title>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

    <style type='text/css'>
      body {
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 14px;        
      }

      .tabs-menu {
        height: 30px;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
      }

      .tabs-menu li {
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
      }

      .tabs-menu li.current {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        z-index: 5;
      }

      .tabs-menu li a {
        padding: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none; 
      }

      .tabs-menu .current a {
        color: #2e7da3;
      }

      .tab {
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: auto;
      }

      .tab-content {
        width: 660px;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
      }

      #tab-1 {
        display: block;   
      }

    </style>




    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
      $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
            var tab = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
            $(tab).fadeIn();
          });
        });
      });//]]> 

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tabs-container">
      <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor....</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
          <p>Donec semper dictum.... </p>

        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
          <p>Duis egestas fermentum.... </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
          <p>Proin sollicitudin tincidunt.... </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't try to copy the source of JSFiddle, you can but it is rendered source relative to JSFiddle.

Second, you should look at the includes on the sidebar. So we see that we have JQuery 1.7.2 and normalize.css. Go and get those from the package maintainers, not from a third party, and include them in the head of your document.

Third, include the CSS in a style tag in the head of the document, then include the HTML in the body. The JavaScript should be included in a script tag at the end of the body so you don't need the document ready wrapper.

There was a couple modifications to the CSS to switch from float to inline-block, remove some margins and the bullets for the list. Et voilà!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css" />
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 14px;        
      }

      .tabs-menu {
        height: 30px;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .tabs-menu li {
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
      }

      .tabs-menu li.current {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 0px;
      }

      .tabs-menu li a {
        padding: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none; 
      }

      .tabs-menu .current a {
        color: #2e7da3;
      }

      .tab {
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: auto;
      }

      .tab-content {
        width: 660px;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
      }

      #tab-1 {
        display: block;   
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tabs-container">
      <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam pretium, est at congue mattis, nibh eros pharetra lectus, nec posuere libero dui consectetur arcu. Quisque convallis facilisis fermentum. Nam tincidunt, diam nec dictum mattis, nunc dolor ultrices ipsum, in mattis justo turpis nec ligula. Curabitur a ante mauris. Integer placerat imperdiet diam, facilisis pretium elit mollis pretium. Sed lobortis, eros non egestas suscipit, dui dui euismod enim, ac ultricies arcu risus at tellus. Donec imperdiet congue ligula, quis vulputate mauris ultrices non. Aliquam rhoncus, arcu a bibendum congue, augue risus tincidunt massa, vel vehicula diam dolor eget felis.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
          <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra. </p>

        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
          <p>Duis egestas fermentum ipsum et commodo. Proin bibendum consectetur elit, hendrerit porta mi dictum eu. Vestibulum adipiscing euismod laoreet. Vivamus lobortis tortor a odio consectetur pulvinar. Proin blandit ornare eros dictum fermentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur laoreet, ante aliquet molestie laoreet, lectus odio fringilla purus, id porttitor erat velit vitae mi. Nullam posuere nunc ut justo sollicitudin interdum. Donec suscipit eros nec leo condimentum fermentum. Nunc quis libero massa. Integer tempus laoreet lectus id interdum. Integer facilisis egestas dui at convallis. Praesent elementum nisl et erat iaculis a blandit ligula mollis. Vestibulum vitae risus dui, nec sagittis arcu. Nullam tortor enim, placerat quis eleifend in, viverra ac lacus. Ut aliquam sapien ut metus hendrerit auctor dapibus justo porta. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
          <p>Proin sollicitudin tincidunt quam, in egestas dui tincidunt non. Maecenas tempus condimentum mi, sed convallis tortor iaculis eu. Cras dui dui, tempor quis tempor vitae, ullamcorper in justo. Integer et lorem diam. Quisque consequat lectus eget urna molestie pharetra. Cras risus lectus, lobortis sit amet imperdiet sit amet, eleifend a erat. Suspendisse vel luctus lectus. Sed ac arcu nisi, sit amet ornare tellus. Pellentesque nec augue a nibh pharetra scelerisque quis sit amet felis. Nullam at enim at lacus pretium iaculis sit amet vel nunc. Praesent sapien felis, tincidunt vitae blandit ut, mattis at diam. Suspendisse ac sapien eget eros venenatis tempor quis id odio. Donec lacus leo, tincidunt eget molestie at, pharetra cursus odio. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent().addClass("current");
          $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
          var tab = $(this).attr("href");
          $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
          $(tab).fadeIn();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three CSS files you're missing:

http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css

http://jsfiddle.net/css/result-light.css

http://jsfiddle.net/css/embedded-light.css?update10082015

Copy those into your project folder, remove the "/css/" part of the relative URL from the links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="result-light.css">
```

And, no need to double wrap window.load and document.ready:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
});//]]> 

</script>
```

Should be:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

This may not be the only issue, but a place to start.

Comment: Thanks. The second link is not dead but seems to have no content. Adding the first file definitely made a difference. :)

Comment: Looks like a third as well (perhaps the most important): http://jsfiddle.net/css/embedded-light.css?update10082015